# How to calculate factorial of 2n recursively?

Tags: recursion

I have encountered the following problem: n is positive non-zero integer and I have to calculate the product of : (2n)! 
 
how can I do this recursively

Comment: I believe you should take a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me explain the problem and how to solve it to you:

We will create a function that calculates (2n)! (which mean we will calculate (2n)*(2n-1)*(2n-2)...*2*1

So the stop condition is when (2n) reaches 1, and when (2n) bigger than 1 just do 2n*(2n-1).

```
//you have to pass (2n) into the argument
public static int calculate(int valueOf2n) {
    //stop condition
    if(valueOf2n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return valueOf2n*calculate(valueOf2n - 1);
    }
}
```